# What are all the supported frameworks for DNX 1.0.0-beta8?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dnx

Currently I've a project.json files which lists:

```
"frameworks": {
        "net40": {
        },
        "net45": {
        },
        "dnx451": {
        },
        "dnxcore5": {
        },
        "netcore5": {

        }
    }
```

However, is this valid ?
And what's the difference between dnx451, dnxcore5 and netcore5 ?

Comment: There is no reason to assume it is not valid, the project is generating runtimes like colored jelly beans.  As long as you have it installed on the machine, like .net40 or net45, or can download the reference assemblies and runtime from Nuget, like the others, then it is valid.  For now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is this valid?

All those frameworks are *theoretically* valid. Not all will work however.

Those are also called "moniker" and they are going to be validated against NuGet packages to retrieve the proper assembly. If the NuGet packages can't find a matching moniker, it will just not create a proper reference.

More over, child dependency must also support to moniker otherwise it will just simply will not be able to load the reference.

#### What's the difference between `dnx451`, `dnxcore5`, `netcore5`?

`dnx451` is referencing the full desktop framework which includes WinForms, System.Web, WPF and everything else.

`dnxcore5` is the new .NET framework that is cross-plat and is compatible on Linux/OSX and, of course, Windows.

`netcore5` is the same as `dnxcore5` but only from and older beta.

#### Additional recommended reading

If you want to know more about the Core Framework (CoreFX), I recommend reading about the [.NET Standard Platform](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/standard-platform.md) which does a fairly good job of indicating what is supported where and by what.